# Deployed VUE-JS App cant connect to deployed FastAPI-Websocket

Tags: vue.js, websocket, apache2, fastapi

So im wrote a little Game for me and my friends in VueJS and FastAPI (with WebSockets)
On LocalHost everything works fine and i thought i could deploy it to my IONOS-Playground-Server (the one for 1€).

FastAPI-APP runs on my Server with this service-File:

```
[Unit]
Description=BuergerMafia Fastapi-Server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
Environment=SECRET_KEY=blasdasdasfoi123124jh1
Environment=PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
WorkingDirectory=/home/buc/fastapi_buergermafia
ExecStart=/home/buc/fastapi_buergermafia/.venv/bin/uvicorn fastapi_buergermafia:app
Restart=always
PrivateTmp=true
NoNewPrivileges=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The App runs on Port :8000

I wrote a ApacheConfig-File like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test-backend.buergermafia.de

    ProxyPass /ws ws://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse /ws ws://127.0.0.1:8000/

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =test-backend.buergermafia.de
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

After that i ran certbot to use Certificates for HTTPS and WSS.
I can access the Site https://test-backend.buergermafia.de/docs and everything seems alright.

FastAPI-APP Middleware-Settings look like this cause i am getting clueless.

```py
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],  # Erlaubt alle HTTP-Methoden
    allow_headers=["*"],  # Erlaubt alle HTTP-Header
)
```

**VUE-JS .env**

```
VUE_APP_BACKEND=https://test-backend.buergermafia.de
VUE_APP_WS_BACKEND=wss://test-backend.buergermafia.de
```

**Main VUE-Component that should connect to the WebSocket**

```
created() {
    this.ws = new WebSocket(process.env.VUE_APP_WS_BACKEND + '/ws/');
    //   'ws://localhost:8000/ws'
    this.ws.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      this.lobbies = data
    });
  }
```

The VUE-App runs also on the same Server but is served under another subdomain
**Apache-Config for Frontend**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testfrontend.buergermafia.de

    DocumentRoot /home/buc/test_frontend
    <Directory /home/buc/test_frontend/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =testfrontend.buergermafia.de
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

After that i ran certbot for that Config as well.

I can open up the WebSite and it interacts with the REST-API-Part of the Backend well.
But it cant connect to the WebSocket and i cant seem to figure out, what i am doing wrong:

[ErrorMessage in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QJZT.png)

Checked the Journal of the FastAPI-APP and all i am seeing is that the connection is rejected:

```
INFO:     ('<IP>', 0) - "WebSocket /" 403
INFO:     connection rejected (403 Forbidden)
INFO:     connection closed
```

What exactly am i doing wrong?

I tried it without HTTPS and WSS but it wont work either.

I tried to specifically allow only the Frontend-URL as Origin for CORS

I tried to bind the Certificates in the Service-File of the Backend with Uvicorn --ssl-key= --ssl-certifcate=

Im trying to connect to the WebSocket Server.